# Extract column values of Dataframe as List in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert a string column of a data frame to a list. What I can find from the `Dataframe` API is RDD, so I tried converting it back to RDD first, and then apply `toArray` function to the RDD. In this case, the length and SQL work just fine. However, the result I got from RDD has square brackets around every element like this `[A00001]`. I was wondering if there's an appropriate way to convert a column to a list or a way to remove the square brackets.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [ways to solve it with Spark 2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44082786/1592191)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

This should return the collection containing single list:

```
dataFrame.select("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect()
```

Without the mapping, you just get a Row object, which contains every column from the database.

Keep in mind that this will probably get you a list of Any type. Ïf you want to specify the result type, you can use .asInstanceOf[YOUR_TYPE] in `r => r(0).asInstanceOf[YOUR_TYPE]` mapping

P.S. due to automatic conversion you can skip the `.rdd` part.

Comment: For some strange reason it works the other way round (Spark 2.1.0) `collect().map(r => r(0))` - does this order have any disadvantages ?

Comment: Can be slower - your solution first collects all the data on the driver, and after that it does the mapping on the driver (without executors aid), using only the processing power of single driver.

Answer (score 93):

## With Spark 2.x and Scala 2.11

I'd think of 3 possible ways to convert values of a specific column to a List.

#### Common code snippets for all the approaches

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate    
import spark.implicits._ // for .toDF() method

val df = Seq(
    ("first", 2.0),
    ("test", 1.5), 
    ("choose", 8.0)
  ).toDF("id", "val")
```

### Approach 1

```
df.select("id").collect().map(_(0)).toList
// res9: List[Any] = List(one, two, three)
```

What happens now? We are collecting data to Driver with `collect()` and picking element zero from each record.

*This could not be an excellent way of doing it, Let's improve it with the next approach.*

---

### Approach 2

```
df.select("id").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toList 
//res10: List[Any] = List(one, two, three)
```

How is it better? We have distributed map transformation load among the workers rather than a single Driver.

*I know `rdd.map(r => r(0))` does not seems elegant you. So, let's address it in the next approach.*

---

### Approach 3

```
df.select("id").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList 
//res11: List[String] = List(one, two, three)
```

Here we are not converting DataFrame to RDD. Look at `map` it won't accept `r => r(0)`(or `_(0)`) as the previous approach due to encoder issues in DataFrame. So end up using `r => r.getString(0)` and it would be addressed in the next versions of Spark.

> ### Conclusion

All the options give the same output but 2 and 3 are effective, finally 3rd one is effective and elegant(I'd think).

[Databricks notebook](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5537430417240233/312903576646278/3506802399907740/latest.html)

Comment: I had tried several ways, for a databricks job running on a job cluster, but the list wasn't getting populated. It worked locally but not in a cluster job. Approach 1 solved my issue. Appreciated.

Answer (score 31):

I know the answer given and asked for is assumed for Scala, so I am just providing a little snippet of Python code in case a PySpark user is curious. The syntax is similar to the given answer, but to properly pop the list out I actually have to reference the column name a second time in the mapping function and I do not need the select statement.

i.e. A DataFrame, containing a column named "Raw"

To get each row value in "Raw" combined as a list where each entry is a row value from "Raw" I simply use:

```
MyDataFrame.rdd.map(lambda x: x.Raw).collect()
```

Comment: This gives a list of Row objects. What if you want a list of the values?

Comment: This gives a list of values.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! This works for me great just wondering if there is a way to speed this up, it runs pretty slow

Answer (score 9):

In Scala and Spark 2+, try this (assuming your column name is "s"):
`df.select('s).as[String].collect`

Answer (score 4):

```
List<String> whatever_list = df.toJavaRDD().map(new Function<Row, String>() {
    public String call(Row row) {
        return row.getAs("column_name").toString();
    }
}).collect();

logger.info(String.format("list is %s",whatever_list)); //verification
```

Since no one has given any solution in java(Real Programming Language)
Can thank me later

Answer (score 3):

```
sqlContext.sql(" select filename from tempTable").rdd.map(r => r(0)).collect.toList.foreach(out_streamfn.println) //remove brackets
```

it works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Below is for Python-

```
df.select("col_name").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

Comment: Others answers (such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841515/6807769) are similar

Comment: @VincentDoba  - There will always be similar answers for a query. It's not the same and none of the answers use flatMap in python in this thread. It's very easy to downvote rather than helping people. Anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df.select(col("column_name")).collect()
```

here collect is functions which in turn convert it to list.
Be ware of using the list on the huge data set. It will decrease performance.
It is good to check the data.

Comment: This didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

An updated solution that gets you a list:

```
dataFrame.select("YOUR_COLUMN_NAME").map(r => r.getString(0)).collect.toList
```

Answer (score -1):

This is java answer.

```
df.select("id").collectAsList();
```